# How to make a script to take newly updated files from a folder and transfer them to another by name

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to extract html files that automatically update from one folder to another. I am searching them by a auto generated code for every file. The files are named like : Diagnostics (2022'12'02 @1403'01''918''').html
Where the code after the @ changes on every app start and close. Sometimes there a more than one file and they have the extension “p1” , “p2” ,”p3” , … “pn” and I want all the files with the @ code to be taken and moved to another folder. This is what I came up with as my strategy was to take the most recent file created (which is most of the time Diagnostics (xxxxxx)pn.html and wanted to an script to copy the part from Diagnostics - xxx) and then find the other files.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\User\something\Temporary Files\'|Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1
$b = Get-Content "C:\Users\something\Desktop\test.txt"
Echo $a
Out-File -FilePath .\test.txt|
Get-Content -Path .\test.txt
```

This creates a new file with the name of the file but I don’t know how to extract the useful part as a string and then search it in the directory and copy it to another folder on the desktop. This is done with Powershell as I want to make it a Bat file tha when executed does the whole process but coudnt do it with bat files only.
Thanks for the help in advance and I’m happy to join the community :)
Note: this is what the file test.txt has

Directory: C:\Users\something\Temporary Files

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---l         12/2/2022   2:09 PM         706568 Diagnostics (2022'12'02 @1403'01''918''').html

This is what I came up with
Note: this is my first time playing with .bat files and with Powershell so I understand it’s not really much but… :D

Comment: Again!!! for debug use : $a | format-table.  You will see the filename is in the property .Name. So you need to use $a.Name

Comment: Would `move "C:\User\something\Temporary Files\*@*.html" "C:...\desktop...\directoryondesktop"` where `"C:...\desktop...\directoryondesktop"` is the desktop directory to which you want to move the files do what you want? Test against a dummmy directory first..

Comment: Well it does the trick yes but the "Diagnostics (xxxxxx).html files are generated with random " xxxx" numbers and i need a specific part of those numbers in order to copy the .html files to the other location. For instanse there is the file : "Diagnostics (2022'12'02 @1403'01''918''').html" that has the @ numbers and after a closing and opening the aplication there is a new file with diferent numbers after the @ symbol. + sometimes there are more than one DIagnostics file with the same @numbers but with additional letters like so : Diagnostics (2022'12'02 @1403'01''918''')p1.html

Comment: I managed to do it with this setup , probably not the cleanest but still got the job done :) Thanks for the help anyway and happy coding dudes:) 
`set diagDir=%userprofile%\somewhere\Temporary Files
set scriptPath=%cd%
cd "%diagDir%"
DIR *.html /B /O-D /TW > allDiagnosticsList.txt
set /P lastDiagnostic=<allDiagnosticsList.txt
set diagnosticsTimestamp=%lastDiagnostic:~13,27%
set newDirectoryName=ExtractedDiagnostics-%diagnosticsTimestamp%
cd "%scriptPath%"
MKDIR "%newDirectoryName%"
cd "%diagDir%"
XCOPY "%diagDir%\*%diagnosticsTimestamp%*" "%scriptPath%\%newDirectoryName%" /y `